# No Popular Question badges awarded for 27 May?

Tags: discussion, badges, data-dump

While playing with the data dump for a blog post ([Stack Overflow: Badge Analysis Over Time](http://geekomatic.ch/2009/06/11/1244725080000.html)), I see that no Popular Question badges were awarded for 27 May, which is odd.

The missing badges show in both the absolute graph (first) and the relative graph (second), as we see below. The relative graph is great for seeing the relative trends, and also to see if the badges were or were not retroactively.. it looks to me as if they were not awarded.

[image: Absolute graph]
[image: Relative graph]

Did this really happen? Or is there a fault somewhere? At no point since the early days has there ever been no Popular Question badges awarded, especially mid-week.

Comment: Actually it looks like there are several spikes on that day, both up and down.

Comment: Um, not really.  Note that this is just one week we see above, and those 'spikes' you refere to are all within the norms.  But, the no popular question is a solid anomaly.  0?  Well outside the std dev, had occured since early days (and lower usage), and happened on a Wednesday, one of the busiest days of all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wasn't that the day no views were being counted? No views == no popular questions

There's a [UserVoice ticket for this](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/200269-illogical-viewcount-bug-):

> date encoding error -- fixed!
>   `closed on 05.28.2009`

Comment: Ahhh...I'd buy that explanation for a dollar.  Was this outage discussed anywhere where I could verify it?

Comment: Yep, found a uservoice ticket for it, which was closed on the 28th..

Answer (score 0):

I think Jarrod turned off the badge tasks accidentally at one point.

Comment: Would that not have stopped other badges from being issued as well?

Comment: not sure. all the other badges were DOWN though, per your graph.

Comment: The dip in the other badges is just because of the stacked graph type, the other badges were not really down (you can at least clearly see that "Organizer" went up). It would be interesting to see the complete number of badges awarded per day though.

Comment: I turned it off to foster discussions about badge grant anomalies :)

Comment: @Jeff: The graph is relative, each badge percentage of the whole.  Showing data like this makes it easier to show changes in the pattern.

Comment: @Jarraod: Stop messing with my mind!  It is small and fragile. :P

Comment: @Palmin: I can whip that graph up quick...will do...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it is a requirement to systematically reach this badge every single day.

Comment: oh, maybe for YOU, it is not a requirement. slacker.

Comment: I'd call it an 'expectation', and hence the question

Comment: I might be a slacker, so were others on that specific day. Even John Skeet has days off, you know.

Comment: Days have Jon Skeet off, you mean.